# How to get `C-h m` to show its output in the same window?

Tags: dired, window, help

When I type `C-h m` in `dired` mode, it opens in a different window. I'd like it to open in the same. How can I do this?

In the future, is there an internal reference for questions like this that is quick to access. How should help be navigated in general?

Comment: " it opens in a different window" Are you sure you didn't mean buffer? You can list buffers with `C-x C-b`.

Comment: I meant window. As in a new "window" within Emacs, the way Emacs uses the term.

Comment: Your question title contradicted the question - one said the problem was that it doesn't use the same window and the other asked how to get it to use a different window. I've changed the title to fit the question as posed.

Comment: Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Yes. Try it yourself: Here are steps to reproduce: `emacs -Q` then `C-x C-f .emacs.d/init.el <RET>` then `C-x d`, and it should open in a new window. Emacs 30.5.0.